# I want some custom changes on my product page

Tags: wordpress, replace, wordpress-theming, product, customization

1. I want the selling price placed in the next line and after the next line Inclusive of all taxes (this is a custom text which display in every product)
2. I want My variation selection option next line after the price & before the add to cart.

as it is as an amazon product page. can anyone help me with it, I’ve searched a lot on google but it’s not working.

Product Page Link - https://crowcrowcrow.com/shop/a0000022hharl01

I'm new to this group so if I'm posted the wrong question then am apologize in advanced

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Flatsome theme which lets you build custom layouts for your product pages. [Here's a detailed tutorial that guides you through it](https://docs.uxthemes.com/article/245-how-to-create-a-custom-product-page)

Here's the relevant step-by-steps for you:

1. Go to Your WP Dashboard -> Blocks -> Add New
2. Create a new block called Product Layout
3. Go to Theme Options -> Shop -> Product Page
4. Enable "Custom" in the product page layout options
5. Now visit an existing product on the frontend of the website
6. Hover over Edit Product and select "Edit Product Layout with UX Builder"

You'll now be able to drag and drop the different options into the desired location.